# Roughly how many Martians are there?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, supergirl, supergirl-2015

In *Supergirl*, there are White Martians and Green Martians. The majority of White Martians perpetrated a genocide of all but a handful of Green Martians. The only remaining Green Martians, of course, are

> J’onn J’onzz, and, as revealed recently, his father.

That said, there are still decently many White Martians left on Mars. My initial impression was that there was an enormous number. On the other hand, the number of White Martians guarding the psychic staff in Season 3, Episode 3 was fairly small, as was the number of resistance fighters sent against them (despite that being the most pivotal mission). Further, the Resistance was said to be close to winning, despite apparently being small. All of this points to much lower numbers.

So how many White Martians are there on Mars? Hundreds, thousands, millions? Further, how does this compare to the pre-genocide population of both species?